# How to get the exact co-ordinate od SVG using svg.js or jquery?

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg, jquery-svg, svg.js

how to get the SVG image exact position of all element(rect,path) using svg.js or jquery, I have to try to get but vary from all element ex(rect, circle,path), Please any one help.

Comment: Please provide code, examples and clarify your language. It's not clear what you are asking for

Comment: i have a 2 svg image one image have a path element another image have rect element how bot are same place but X,Y values are different i want take a exact position svg element.

Comment: I suspect what you mean is that not all elements use x,y. E.g a circle has cx,cy. So x,y doesn't have an exact meaning for ALL elements. You could either grab the x,y or cx,cy of rects, circles. If you need things like 'group' elements, you may need to get the bounding box getBBox() and use that as a reference, e.g element.getBBox().x

Comment: i have tried getBBox(). it's returned co-ordinates(0,0)